# React Component User Not in State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

COnsider the following:

```
 componentDidMount(){
    this.props.requestUser(this.props.match.params.userID).then(res => 
      {
        this.pageOwner = res.user;
      debugger;
     })

  }
```

Why is my this.pageOwner still returning undefined? I have been trying my as off to get a user into a state that my user profile can actually acces.

Comment: What is `this` inside the anonymous arrow function?

Comment: but this isn't a state, and it is an async operation, so only when your request completed it will be there (so most probably after the first render). If you want to handle this, make sure you check that the pageOwner is not empty before trying to render its properties. Also, only a `this.setState` will cause your component to rerender (or a props change) ), as it is now, there is nothing that will cause your component to rerender

Comment: Where are you trying to access `this.pageOwner`?

Comment: Is it undefined after you console.log it in the callback function or somewhere else, maybe in `render()`?

Comment: it's undefined when i use the chrome console

Comment: @AaronGodhard can you add you full component code so that its better to have a wider look and help you better ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access `this.pageOwner`, you need to do so after the `this.props.requestUser()` async function has completed. You're currently getting the user in `componentDidMount()`, so your `render()` will initially see `this.pageOwner` as `undefined` until the async call is finished.

Additionally, it might be better to store the result of your async call in `state` so that your component will re-render once the value is filled.

Comment: Whats that going to look like?

Comment: What's which going to look like?

Answer (score 0):

As @colin said, put it in `this.state`. If you are getting an error in the `render()` function, then just make your render like so:

```
constructor() {
 super();
 this.state = {
   pageOwner: null
 }
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.props.requestUser(this.props.match.params.userID).then(res => 
 {
  this.setState({pageOwner: res.user});
  debugger;
 })
}

render() {
 if(this.state.pageOwner) 
   return ( ... )
 else 
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Won't this always return `null` unless something else triggers a re-render?

Comment: Yes, you are right and I edited my answer according to what you said

Comment: react-dom.development.js:512 Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: I guess it's because the arrow syntax function. Try `(function(res) { ... })` instead of `(res => { ... })`

Comment: or just save `this` in a variable before calling the `this.props.requestUser` function, like `var component = this` and then inside the callback call `component.setState({ ... })`

Comment: be careful with setting state in a callback, when the component got unmounted already, you will exactly the above error given by @AaronGodhard